# What is full-stack javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I believe "full-stack" means that a language can handle both the server and client side of things. I have heard that javascript is now able to handle the server side now. I have also heard of node.js but am not 100% sure what that is. What exactly is full-stack javascript? it seems to be the talk of the web.

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/21/introduction-to-full-stack-javascript/

Comment: Don't know what node.js is? There's a site for that: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: In addition to node, there is [vertx](http://vertx.io) as well as Oracle's [Avatar.js](https://avatar-js.java.net/) project which runs on Nashorn, the JVM javascript engine (although still appears pretty immature - wait to see where it goes). Also, you can include the datastore in the full stack if using Mongo, Couch, Riak, and even Postgres (with [PL/V8](https://code.google.com/p/plv8js/wiki/PLV8)). I implemented some server-side javascript support in an older java framework using Rhino as well, but it would be insane to do that today - it's a very, very dated/slow engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"full-stack javascript" is idea and marketing term that says that JavaScript is used for both server and client side.

Node.js http://nodejs.org/ was the first JavaScript platform to become popular and set standard for server side JavaScript.
It is using V8 engine from WebKit open-source project, that power Apple browsers and Google Chrome (before they forked it into new own project.)

JavaScript cab be also used for development of Windows 8, GNOME and Mozilla FireOS apps.

Some companies promotes using their frameworks and packs as stack (choices for framework already made)